# How is the map used in the following line of code?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

What does the following function do?

```
dist = map(lambda i : map(lambda j : j , i) , graph)

graph[][] = { {0,   5,  INF, 10},
                    {INF,  0,  3,  INF},
                    {INF, INF, 0,   1},
                    {INF, INF, INF, 0} }
```

Comment: Will this code even run in python? graph[][] should give an error

Comment: I suspect the brackets are not the right kind either. `{x, y, z}` is a `set`, which has no order, and since sets are unhashable, you can't nest one inside another. An adjacency list for a graph should probably be using nested lists or dictionaries.